# On subgroups invariant under the diagonal automorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number and $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ be a finite field of order $p$. Let $G=GL_{n}(\mathbb{F}_{p})$ denote the general linear group and $U_{n}$
denote the unitriangular group of $n\times n$ upper triangular matrices with
ones on the diagonal, over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p}$. Let $T$ be the diagonal subgroup of $G$.

**Definition:** Let $D\in T$. A diagonal automorphism $\varphi _{D}$ of $U_{n}$
is an automorphism defined by $\varphi_{D}(M)=DMD^{-1}$. A subgroup U of $U_{n}$ is called invariant under the diagonal automorphisms of $U_{n}$ if $\varphi_{D}(M)\in U$ for all $M\in U$.

**Question:** Do the subgroups of order $p^{2}$ of $U_{n}$ are invariants under the diagonal automorphisms of $U_{n}$.

Comment: $U_n$ has lots of subgroups of order $p^2$ for $n \ge 3$, and they are not all invariant under diagonal automorphisms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are in general some subgroups of order $p^2$ which are  not $T$-invariant when $p$ is odd.

For instance, take
$$
H:=\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & a & 0 & b\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & a\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\mid
a,b\in\mathbb{F}_p
\right\},
$$
It is not conjugated to itself by $\text{diag} (2,1,1,1)$.

**Added later**

It occurred to me that it might be interesting to know whether the **normal** subgroups of the unitriangular group are fixed by the diagonal group. The facts of the matter are (when $n\geqslant 3$ and $p$ is odd):

there are exactly $p+1$ such subgroups, namely the maximal subgroups of the second centre;

these may labelled in a natural way by the ratios $\alpha : \beta$ for all $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{F}_p$;

of these, the subgroups labelled $0$ and $\infty$ are fixed by the diagonal group, and the others permuted transitively.

The calculations which establish these facts are fairly routine; one begins by establishing that the centre consists of those unitriangular matrices whose only non-zero off-diagonal entry is the last in the first row, and that the second centre consists of those unitriangular matrices whose only non-zero off-diagonal entries are the last two in the first row and the first two in the last column.

Comment: Thank you [ancientmathematicianh](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/414424/ancientmathematician) for your answer. Have you a reference of what you added in the last of your answer?.

Comment: No reference, just the proof I've given.